# Flask 400 bad request when passing json to post request

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I am trying to pass json from javascript to my python flask backend and return that back to my javascript.

I am roughly following https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/python-javascript-communicate-json/

When I press the button to send the post request, in my worker function, request.is_json prints out as true, but then when I try to call request.get_json(), flask 400's out. I am fairly confident my json is well formed, what else am I missing here?

web.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, Response
import random, json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def output():
    return render_template("index.html", name="Joe")

@app.route('/receiver', methods = ['POST'])
def worker():

    print(request.is_json)
    data = request.get_json()

    print(data)

    return jsonify(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run("0.0.0.0", "5000")
```

index.html:

```
{{ name }}

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // setup some JSON to use
    var cars = [
        { "make":"Porsche", "model":"911S" }
    ];

    window.onload = function() {
        // setup the button click
        document.getElementById("theButton").onclick = function() {
            doWork()
        };
    }

    $.ajaxSetup({
      contentType: "application/json"
    });

    function doWork() {
        // ajax the JSON to the server
        $.post("receiver", cars, function(response){
            console.log(cars);
            console.log("");
            console.log(response);
        });
        // stop link reloading the page
        event.preventDefault();
    }
</script>

<p>This will send data using AJAX to Python: </p>
<a href="" id="theButton">Click Me</a>
```

[terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtvb7.png)

[webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHMHW.png)

Comment: try to send the same post request from a request generator like postman and see if you get same error.

Comment: I believe the issue is you are sending a JSON array. Prior to 1.0 Flask.jsonify did not support Arrays for dumping, and I haven't verified it (because I don't have any pre 1.0 machines right now) but I would guess it's symmetrical. Try sending an object instead of an Array. More here:  http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/security/#json-security